# Mulitselect dropdown - filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following multi select dropdown menu:

```
<div data-ng-dropdown-multiselect options="vm.translatedRoles" selected-model="vm.translatedRolesModel" external-id-prop="label" enableSearch="true"></div>
```

and the selected items are stored in vm.translatedRolesModel and looks like this:

```
vm.translatedRolesModel = [{id:0, label:'Role1'}, ...]
```

and this it the ng-repeat container:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="scheduleResponseContent in tableData.scheduleResponseContents | filter:vm.translatedRolesModel"...
```

Now I will filter the ng-repeat items of the **translatedRolesModel**- list.
Is there a simple way of doing this? - **| filter:vm.translatedRolesModel"** does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function to filter the values.

e.g.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="....| filter : vm.filterSelected"...
```

The create function `filterSelected` as

```
 vm.filterSelected= function(element) {
      var matched =_.find(vm.translatedRolesModel, { name:element.name });
      return matched !== undefined;
    };
```

Note : I have used `lodash` function `_.find`. You can match the filter any other way.